# Using sqlite prepared statements with SELECT

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a little pet project that organizes people's comic books and stores metadata about them in an SQL database.  For the sake of correctness, I'm using prepared statements instead of Python's built in string operators, but I can't quite get it to work right.  This is a brief snippet of code I've made to illustrate the problems I'm having:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("MyComicBox.db")

curs = connection.cursor()

curs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comic_collection (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, series TEXT, publisher TEXT, issue TEXT, tags TEXT)")

connection.commit()

def addComic(series = "", publisher = "", issue = "", tags = ""):
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO comic_collection (series, publisher, issue, tags) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (series, publisher, issue, tags))
    connection.commit()

def search(attribute, val):
    """
    Do an SQL query for all comics where attribute LIKE val and return a list of them.
    """

#   cmd = "SELECT * from comic_collection WHERE %s LIKE '%s'" % (attribute, val)
#   curs.execute(cmd)

    cmd = "SELECT * from comic_collection WHERE ? LIKE ?"
    curs.execute(cmd, (attribute, val))

    results = []

    for comic in curs:
        results.append(comic)

    return results

addComic(series = "Invincible Iron Man", issue = "500", publisher = "Marvel Comics", tags = "Iron Man; Spider-Man; Mandarin")


searchResults = search("issue", "500")

for item in searchResults:
    print item
```

My problem is in the search function.  The query doesn't return anything unless I replace the two lines where I execute cmd using the ? operator with the two (commented out) lines where I execute cmd using Python's built in string operators.  Can anybody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is technically just a 'parameterized statement', not a 'prepared statement'. A 'prepared statement' is usually a 'parameterized statement' (unless it has no parameters) but a handle to an instance of the parsed statement is kept and reused, instead of the SQL text being passed each time. AFAIK, prepared statements are unsupported by Python's SQLite module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of `attribute` is wrong. Imagine that the `?` already includes its surrending `''`s.

One way would be to do it this way:

```
cmd = "SELECT * from comic_collection WHERE %s LIKE ?" % attribute
curs.execute(cmd, val)
```

but you absolutely have to ensure that attribute does not come from an untrusted source here or that it only has valid values, maybe by

```
assert attribute in ('series', 'publisher', 'issue', 'tags')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't use placeholders for column names - they are for values only. So this would work:

```
cmd = "SELECT * from comic_collection WHERE %s LIKE ?" % attribute
curs.execute(cmd, (val,))
```

Answer (score -3):

From what I recall of prepared statements in the sqlite C api, you may have to write it like this:

```
cmd = "SELECT * from comic_collection WHERE ?1 LIKE ?2"
```